# dojox chart update/destroy does not work after dojo.byId

Tags: charts, dojo, destroy

I created a dojo chart using;

```
var pieChart = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("pieChart");
```

Afterwards I want to update/destroy this chart. SO I do;

```
var pieChart = dojo.byId("pieChart");
pieChart.destroy();
```

This seems to be not functional. Am I doing something wrong here?

best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using dojox so dojo.byId will not return javascript object try using dijit.byId I think it'll work as suggested below:

var pieChart = dijit.byId("pieChart");
pieChart.destroy();

the same problem I was facing with dojox.form.BusyButton after a great effort I found this...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem, where I created the chart in one place and then wanted to destroy it in another, but I didn't have a reference to the chart object. The only solution I found is to empty the DOM node you used to make the chart:

```
dojo.empty("pieChart");
```

Comment: For dojo +1.7 use domConstruct.empty("chartNode") instead: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/empty.html

Answer (score 0):

The second variable will reference DOM object, not the javascript object that store chart object.

```
var pieChart = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("pieChart");
pieChartDom = dojo.byId("pieChart"); //you cannot destroy, 
pieChart.destroy();  //you can destroy, this is original variable
```

I hope it helps.