# How do I get a handle to my dojo chart to resize it?

Tags: javascript, xpages, dojox.charting

I have a dojo line chart that is contained in a hidden panel.  Naturally, when the page is opened, the chart is sized with default width and height.  When I display the panel though, I want to resize the chart to fit the panel.  I found the statement, chart.resize(w,h), but I don't know how to use it.  How do I get a handle to the chart itself?

I create the chart using this...

```
var chart3 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("#{id:panelSimpleChart}");
```

but, this just tells the chart where to render.  It's not actually assigning that id to the chart, correct?

I found a post with a reference to doing this...

```
var chart = dijit.byId("#{id:panelSimpleChart}");
if (chart != null ) {
    chart.resize(w,h);
}
```

but, when I try that using my panel name, chart is null.

This seems to be a simple question, but I'm a little baffled here.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is the containing panel markup...

```
<xp:panel id="panelSeatTotals">
    <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:"xspDisplayNone"}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
```

so, it's rendered, but not displayed.

Here's a little more of the code (with irrelevant stuff removed)

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="50" var="asmydata"
    indexVar="asmyindex" value="#{view1}">
    <xp:panel id="panelAsmyDoc">
...
        <xp:table>
...
            <xp:panel id="panelSeatTotals">
                <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:"xspDisplayNone"}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
...
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td
                        style="padding-left:20.0%">
                        <xc:chartLine_AS></xc:chartLine_AS>
                    </xp:td>
```

This is from the chart cc:

```
<xp:panel id="panelSimpleChart"
        style="width:100%; height: 400px;height:200px">

    </xp:panel>
```

and the script...

```
makeCharts3 = function(){
    //line chart
   var chart3 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("#{id:panelSimpleChart}");
...
}
XSP.addOnLoad(makeCharts3);
```

Comment: Based on a similar question here on SO ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610920/dojox-chart-update-destroy-does-not-work-after-dojo-byid ) this should work. Did you make sure that at least the DOM node you created the chart for exists `dojo.byId("#{id:panelSimpleChart}")` ? The computed ID might have changed if you performed a partial refresh on one of the parent elements...

Comment: Page source shows that it's there      div id="view:_id1:CompXPage:_id171:repeat1:0:_id778:panelSimpleChart"

Comment: IMO you should programmatically check that the node with the given ID exists with `dojo.byId` right before trying to get the chart with `dijit.byId`.

Comment: oh, wait, I see what you're saying, since the panel is hidden when the page opens, the id calculated is different than what it is when the panel is displayed, correct?  Is there a way for me to regenerate that id, then? - or, do I have to just reference it explicitly, since I know what it will be?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "hidden". Is it just not displayed (client-side), or not rendered at all (server-side)... Could you add the relevant markup of the XPage to your question? There are multiple possible reasons for the referencing problem you describe.

Comment: Markup was added to my post.

Comment: Actually I meant the whole relevant markup. Anyway: the important thing to know is if both code segments from your question are inside the repeat. Otherwise the generated client-side IDs won't be the same.

Comment: I added more code to my post.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Is all the chart-related code inside the `chartLine_AS` custom control?

Comment: Yes, I added the panel from the cc.

Comment: Is the part where you want to get the chart via `dijit.byId` also inside the chart cc?

Comment: No, it isn't.  But, it is within the same repeat control.  There are 4 options for the line chart, so I planned to put the resize code in the partial refresh event handler, OnComplete event.

Comment: SOLVED  Thank you, Mr. xpages-noob, for responding to my call for help and for your expert insight.  I decided to render the chart AFTER the containing panel was displayed, thus avoiding the resize problem altogether.  So, I copied my makechart function from my custom control and put it in a button on my page - inside my containing panel.  After the panel is displayed, the user must select which chart to display (choice of 4 remember), so in the onComplete event of my radio buttons, I call my new Render button to create the chart.  This works perfectly.  Thank you again for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED Thank you, Mr. xpages-noob, for responding to my call for help and for your expert insight. I decided to render the chart AFTER the containing panel was displayed, thus avoiding the resize problem altogether. So, I copied my makechart function from my custom control and put it in a button on my page - inside my containing panel. After the panel is displayed, the user must select which chart to display (choice of 4 remember), so in the onComplete event of my radio buttons, I call my new Render button to create the chart. This works perfectly. Thank you again for your patience.